# VB.Net Matching and replacing the contents of multiple overlapping sets of brackets in a string

Tags: regex, vb.net, parsing

I am using vb.net to parse my own basic scripting language, sample below. I am a bit stuck trying to deal with the 2 separate types of nested brackets.

```
Assuming name = Sam
Assuming timeFormat = hh:mm:ss
Assuming time() is a function that takes a format string but  
         has a default value and returns a string.


Hello [[name]], the time is [[time(hh:mm:ss)]].
Result: Hello Sam, the time is 19:54:32.

The full time is [[time()]].
Result: The full time is 05/06/2011 19:54:32.

The time in the format of your choice is [[time([[timeFormat]])]].
Result: The time in the format of your choice is 19:54:32.
```

I could in theory change the syntax of the script completely but I would rather not. It is designed like this to enable strings without quotes because it will be included in an  XML file and quotes in that context were getting messy and very prone to errors and readability issues. If this fails I could redesign using something other than quotes to mark out strings but I would rather use this method.

Preferably, unless there is some other way I am not aware of, I would like to do this using regex. I am aware that the standard regex is not really capable of this but I believe this is possible using MatchEvaluators in vb.net and some form of recursion based replacing. However I have not been able to get my head around it for the last day or so, possibly because it is hugely difficult, possibly because I am ill, or possibly because I am plain thick.

I do have the following regex for parts of it.

```
Detecting the parentheses: (\w*?)\((.*?)\)(?=[^\(+\)]*(\(|$))
Detecting the square brackets: \[\[(.*?)\]\](?=[^\[+\]]*(\[\[|$))
```

I would really appreciate some help with this as it is holding the rest of my project back at the moment. And sorry if I have babbled on too much or not put enough detail, this is my first question on here.

Comment: This is a case for a parser.  when you get into the details the regex will make you want to cry. just my .02

Comment: It just feels like something that should be achievable reasonably easily. The script is essentially simple and although I have not looked into it much a parser is probably going to be very complicated. If I cannot find a reasonably easy solution to this it will probably be quicker to redesign the script :(

Comment: And what is the question? What is not working as you want it?

Comment: Rather than it not working as I want, I do not know how to correctly do any of it. I have regex for extracting the top level of each bracket type but I do not know how to structure the recursive replacing. I am looking for any tips or code samples or any other help anyone can offer.

Comment: What I'd do would be first get, through RegEx, all the time keywords, get what's inside the parentheses, replace them accordingly, and then replace [[name]] with a simple String.Replace.

Comment: Forgot to say, that of course I'm aware my solution wouldn't be 100% flexible, and would require "more" code than a parser (although not in this case). But it would be easier to make and understand. It would be a matter of taste, but I'd go with what I said, unless I'd be certain that the list of keywords would be rather big, or the parser logic should be really flexible, or unless I'd want to learn about parsers.

Comment: Thanks @Neverbirth I can get the time keywords and parenthesis easily enough with regex using the "Detecting the parenthesis" part of my original post so the number of them doesn't matter. However, as far as I can tell this method won't deal with the last example given where there can be [[square brackets]] inside parenthesises (What is the plural of parenthesis?) and I need strings to be joined to other values, so there can be a string pretty much anywhere.

Comment: Forgot to say as well, I have not yet studied programming at all and I feel that writing a parser for this maybe a little out of my league and available time for the project as a whole.  Although I confess I am not actually 100% sure at what point code to read this becomes a parser. Would a complex regex system for this not be a regex based parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly simplified version of the code I wrote for this. Thanks for the help everyone and sorry I forgot to post this before. If you have any questions or anything feel free to ask.

```
Function processString(ByVal scriptString As String)
    ' Functions
    Dim pattern As String = "\[\[((\w+?)\((.*?)\))(?=[^\(+\)]*(\(|$))\]\]"
    scriptString = Regex.Replace(scriptString, pattern, New MatchEvaluator(Function(match) processFunction(match)))

    ' Variables
    pattern = "\[\[([A-Za-z0-9+_]+)\]\]"
    scriptString = Regex.Replace(scriptString, pattern, New MatchEvaluator(Function(match) processVariable(match)))
    Return scriptString
End Function

Function processFunction(ByVal match As Match)
    Dim nameString As String = match.Groups(2).Value
    Dim paramString As String = match.Groups(3).Value
    paramString = processString(paramString)
    Select Case nameString
        Case "time"
            Return getLocalValueTime(paramString)
        Case "math"
            Return getLocalValueMath(paramString)
    End Select
    Return ""
End Function

Function processVariable(ByVal match As Match)
    Try
        Return moduleDictionary("properties")("vars")(match.Groups(1).Value)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little sample which might help you iterate through several matches/groups/captures. I realize that I am posting C# code, but it would be easy for you to convert that into VB.Net

```
//these two may be passed in as parameters:
string tosearch;//the string you are searching through
string regex;//your pattern to match
//...
Match m;
CaptureCollection cc;
GroupCollection gc;

Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
m = r.Match(tosearch);
gc = m.Groups;
Debug.WriteLine("Number of groups found = " + gc.Count.ToString());

// Loop through each group.
for (int i = 0; i < gc.Count; i++)
{
  cc = gc[i].Captures;
  counter = cc.Count;
  int grpnum = i + 1;
  Debug.WriteLine("Scanning group: " + grpnum.ToString() );

  // Print number of captures in this group.
  Debug.WriteLine("  Captures count = " + counter.ToString());

  if (cc.Count >= 1)
  {
    foreach (Capture cap in cc)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(string.format("  Capture found: {0}", cap.ToString()));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks good. However, I had already solved this and answered, but a mod deleted it yesterday because I forgot to add the code I used. I will leave this in for now and then I need to work out a small and tidy example of the code I wrote which is more specific to the question.